# SelectOneRadio Problem

Tags: java, jsf, facelets, jsf-2

I'm trying to do a search form, depending on the selected item you can do searchs by start to end or month and year

Is it possible to do a form look like this, with Facelets?
using of preference SelectOneRadio

[alt text http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/5357/imageoq.png](http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/5357/imageoq.png)

Comment: Ummm.. Yes? This is very vague, a little bit more info would be much more helpful.

Comment: i don't know what more information to give, 
i just to know if is possible to create a layout like that using facelet without javascript assistance

Answer (score 3):

It's doable. You'd like to use `<f:ajax>` inside the `<h:selectOneMenu>` to rerender the form on change (click) of the radio buttons. You can use the `@form` identifier for this.

Then, in the input and select elements, you'd like to let `disabled` attribute depend on the radio button selection.

The most tricky part is probably to get it all laid out nicely since the `h:selectOneRadio` itself renders a HTML `<table>`. To group them nicely together, you'd like to split the content over cells of another table and apply CSS `vertical-align: top` to the `td` element containing the `h:selectOneRadio`.

Anyway, here's a full working example to get you started:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:selectOneRadio id="type" value="#{bean.type}" layout="pageDirection" required="true">
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.types}" var="type" itemValue="${type}" itemLabel="" />
            <f:ajax event="click" render="@form" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
        <h:panelGrid columns="4">
            <h:outputLabel for="inputStartDate" value="Start Date" />
            <h:inputText id="inputStartDate" value="#{bean.startDate}" required="true" disabled="#{bean.type != 'INPUT'}">
                <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:outputLabel for="inputEndDate" value="End Date" />
            <h:inputText id="inputEndDate" value="#{bean.endDate}" required="true" disabled="#{bean.type != 'INPUT'}">
                <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:outputLabel for="selectMonth" value="Select Month" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="selectMonth" value="#{bean.month}" required="true" disabled="#{bean.type != 'SELECT'}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{bean.months}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:outputLabel for="selectYear" value="Select Year" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="selectYear" value="#{bean.year}" required="true" disabled="#{bean.type != 'SELECT'}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{bean.years}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:panelGroup />
            <h:panelGroup />
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
            <h:panelGroup />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>        
    <h:messages />
</h:form>
```

Here's how the bean look like:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private enum Type {
        INPUT, SELECT
    }

    private Type type;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private Integer month;
    private Integer year;
    // All with getters and setters.

    private List<Type> types = Arrays.asList(Type.values());
    private List<SelectItem> months = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    private List<Integer> years = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // All with just getters.

    public Bean() {
        String[] monthNames = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            months.add(new SelectItem(i, monthNames[i]));
        }
        for (int i = 2000; i <= 2020; i++) {
            years.add(i);
        }
    }

    public void submit() {
        switch (type) {
            case INPUT:
                System.out.printf("Start Date: %tF, End Date: %tF%n", startDate, endDate);
                break;
            case SELECT:
                System.out.printf("Month: %s, Year: %d%n", months.get(month).getLabel(), year);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Getters and setters here.
}
```

Here's how you can apply CSS to get the radio buttons aligned at top:

```
#form td { vertical-align: top; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course.

Create regular div/css table. where the radio buttons are displayed in one div like this:

facelet page:

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="searchPlace" 
value="#{yourBean.selection}" onclick="enableSearch(this)" layout="pageDirection" border="1">
<f:selectItem itemValue="0" />
```

in the header part, add javascript:

```
function enableSearch(radio){
   if (radio.id == 's1'){
        document.getElementById('startDateText').disabled=false;
        document.getElementById('endDateText').disabled=false;
   }else{
document.getElementById('monthSelect').disabled=false;
        document.getElementById('yearSelect').disabled=false;
   }

}
```

in YourBean.java class:

```
Boolean selection;

public void setSelection(Boolean selection){
this.selection = selection;
}

public String getSelection(){
  return this.selection;
}

public void savePage(){
   ....
   if (selection)
   ..
}
```

and in `savePage()` use the `selection` param to decide the search type.

Comment: thx for the answer, i think i have to use javascript for this xD

Comment: to enable and disable- for sure. I added it in my answer